# json_encode target specific node to get array

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

I'm working with a remote xml that I have to parse to json to push information to a mobile application.
I'm using json_encode to so.

My problem is that for a specific node, sometimes it is an array, sometimes it's a dictionary. I would need to target that specific node and make it always be an array.

My app crashes when it's a dictionary and not an array, so I have to get the [...].

My xml looks like :

```
    <infogeneral>
    <idspotwebcamhd>6</idspotwebcamhd>
    <spot>Anglet Sables d'Or</spot>
    <url/>
    <vagues/>
    <vent>GFS</vent>
    <ventdate>2016-04-12 06:00:00</ventdate>
    <venttimestamp>1460433600</venttimestamp>
    <houle>WW3</houle>
    <houledate>2016-04-12 06:00:00</houledate>
    <houletimestamp>1460433600</houletimestamp>
    <tempeaucelsius>13</tempeaucelsius>
  </infogeneral>
  <day>
    <date>Tue 12 Apr 2016</date>
    <datetimestamp>1460484000</datetimestamp>
    <firstlight>06:55</firstlight>
    <lastlight>21:17</lastlight>
    <creneau>
      <heure>20.00</heure>
      <timestamp>1460484000</timestamp>
      <ventnoeud>9</ventnoeud>
      <ventms/>
      <ventkmh>17</ventkmh>
      <ventbft/>
      <ventmph/>
      <houlemetre>1.10</houlemetre>
      <houlepied/>
      <periode>12</periode>
      <temp>15</temp>
      <ventdirection>so</ventdirection>
      <houledirection>ono</houledirection>
      <pictogramme>3cloud_lightrain.png</pictogramme>
    </creneau>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>Wed 13 Apr 2016</date>
    <datetimestamp>1460505600</datetimestamp>
    <firstlight>06:53</firstlight>
    <lastlight>21:18</lastlight>
    <principal>
      <heure>14:00</heure>
      <pictogrammeprincipal>1cloud_norain.png</pictogrammeprincipal>
      <tempmincelsius>13</tempmincelsius>
      <tempmaxcelsius>17</tempmaxcelsius>
    </principal>
    <creneau>
      <heure>08.00</heure>
      <timestamp>1460527200</timestamp>
      <ventnoeud>17</ventnoeud>
      <ventms/>
      <ventkmh>32</ventkmh>
      <ventbft/>
      <ventmph/>
      <houlemetre>1.20</houlemetre>
      <houlepied/>
      <periode>10</periode>
      <temp>13</temp>
      <ventdirection>sso</ventdirection>
      <houledirection>ono</houledirection>
      <pictogramme>4cloud_norain.png</pictogramme>
    </creneau>
    <creneau>
      <heure>11.00</heure>
      <timestamp>1460538000</timestamp>
      <ventnoeud>19</ventnoeud>
      <ventms/>
      <ventkmh>36</ventkmh>
      <ventbft/>
      <ventmph/>
      <houlemetre>1.40</houlemetre>
      <houlepied/>
      <periode>6</periode>
      <temp>15</temp>
      <ventdirection>so</ventdirection>
      <houledirection>so</houledirection>
      <pictogramme>2cloud_norain.png</pictogramme>
    </creneau>
    <creneau>
      <heure>14.00</heure>
      <timestamp>1460548800</timestamp>
      <ventnoeud>16</ventnoeud>
      <ventms/>
      <ventkmh>29</ventkmh>
      <ventbft/>
      <ventmph/>
      <houlemetre>1.30</houlemetre>
      <houlepied/>
      <periode>6</periode>
      <temp>17</temp>
      <ventdirection>oso</ventdirection>
      <houledirection>so</houledirection>
      <pictogramme>1cloud_norain.png</pictogramme>
    </creneau>
    <creneau>
      <heure>17.00</heure>
      <timestamp>1460559600</timestamp>
      <ventnoeud>7</ventnoeud>
      <ventms/>
      <ventkmh>13</ventkmh>
      <ventbft/>
      <ventmph/>
      <houlemetre>1.00</houlemetre>
      <houlepied/>
      <periode>5</periode>
      <temp>17</temp>
      <ventdirection>no</ventdirection>
      <houledirection>oso</houledirection>
      <pictogramme>0cloud.png</pictogramme>
    </creneau>
    <creneau>
      <heure>20.00</heure>
      <timestamp>1460570400</timestamp>
      <ventnoeud>4</ventnoeud>
      <ventms/>
      <ventkmh>7</ventkmh>
      <ventbft/>
      <ventmph/>
      <houlemetre>0.80</houlemetre>
      <houlepied/>
      <periode>10</periode>
      <temp>15</temp>
      <ventdirection>ne</ventdirection>
      <houledirection>ono</houledirection>
      <pictogramme>0cloud.png</pictogramme>
    </creneau>
  </day>
```

My php to convert xml to json (I load an xml file to save a json file) :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( $in_filepath );
$json = json_encode($xml);
file_put_contents ( $out_filepath, $json );
```

For my testings before production, my php looks like :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/myFile.xml');
$json = json_encode($xml);
print_r($json);
```

After json_encode :

```
"infogeneral":{

    "idspotwebcamhd":"6",
    "spot":"Anglet Sables d'Or",
    "url":{
    },
    "vagues":{
    },
    "vent":"GFS",
    "ventdate":"2016-04-12 06:00:00",
    "venttimestamp":"1460433600",
    "houle":"WW3",
    "houledate":"2016-04-12 06:00:00",
    "houletimestamp":"1460433600",
    "tempeaucelsius":"13"

},
"day":[

    {
        "date":"Tue 12 Apr 2016",
        "datetimestamp":"1460484000",
        "firstlight":"06:55",
        "lastlight":"21:17",
        "creneau":{
            "heure":"20.00",
            "timestamp":"1460484000",
            "ventnoeud":"9",
            "ventms":{
            },
            "ventkmh":"17",
            "ventbft":{
            },
            "ventmph":{
            },
            "houlemetre":"1.10",
            "houlepied":{
            },
            "periode":"12",
            "temp":"15",
            "ventdirection":"so",
            "houledirection":"ono",
            "pictogramme":"3cloud_lightrain.png"
        }
    },
    {
        "date":"Wed 13 Apr 2016",
        "datetimestamp":"1460505600",
        "firstlight":"06:53",
        "lastlight":"21:18",
        "principal":{
            "heure":"14:00",
            "pictogrammeprincipal":"1cloud_norain.png",
            "tempmincelsius":"13",
            "tempmaxcelsius":"17"
        },
        "creneau":[
            {
                "heure":"08.00",
                "timestamp":"1460527200",
                "ventnoeud":"17",
                "ventms":{
                },
                "ventkmh":"32",
                "ventbft":{
                },
                "ventmph":{
                },
                "houlemetre":"1.20",
                "houlepied":{
                },
                "periode":"10",
                "temp":"13",
                "ventdirection":"sso",
                "houledirection":"ono",
                "pictogramme":"4cloud_norain.png"
            },
            {
                "heure":"11.00",
                "timestamp":"1460538000",
                "ventnoeud":"19",
                "ventms":{
                },
                "ventkmh":"36",
                "ventbft":{
                },
                "ventmph":{
                },
                "houlemetre":"1.40",
                "houlepied":{
                },
                "periode":"6",
                "temp":"15",
                "ventdirection":"so",
                "houledirection":"so",
                "pictogramme":"2cloud_norain.png"
            },
            {
                "heure":"14.00",
                "timestamp":"1460548800",
                "ventnoeud":"16",
                "ventms":{
                },
                "ventkmh":"29",
                "ventbft":{
                },
                "ventmph":{
                },
                "houlemetre":"1.30",
                "houlepied":{
                },
                "periode":"6",
                "temp":"17",
                "ventdirection":"oso",
                "houledirection":"so",
                "pictogramme":"1cloud_norain.png"
            },
            {
                "heure":"17.00",
                "timestamp":"1460559600",
                "ventnoeud":"7",
                "ventms":{
                },
                "ventkmh":"13",
                "ventbft":{
                },
                "ventmph":{
                },
                "houlemetre":"1.00",
                "houlepied":{
                },
                "periode":"5",
                "temp":"17",
                "ventdirection":"no",
                "houledirection":"oso",
                "pictogramme":"0cloud.png"
            },
            {
                "heure":"20.00",
                "timestamp":"1460570400",
                "ventnoeud":"4",
                "ventms":{
                },
                "ventkmh":"7",
                "ventbft":{
                },
                "ventmph":{
                },
                "houlemetre":"0.80",
                "houlepied":{
                },
                "periode":"10",
                "temp":"15",
                "ventdirection":"ne",
                "houledirection":"ono",
                "pictogramme":"0cloud.png"
            }
        ]
    },
```

For the 1st day I have only one "creneau" so it crashes.

I tried this out : http://www.binarytides.com/convert-simplexml-object-to-array-in-php/

But it changes the whole tree.

Any idea on how I could get this done ?

Comment: *sometimes it is an array, sometimes it's a dictionary*...how can this be as xml node is neither an array or dictionary? Plus, where is your PHP code to read in XML and run the json_encode?

Comment: I perhaps misspoke, sorry. "creneau" becomes array or dictionary in my app wheter I have one or more than one in the xml. I just put the php code I use.

Answer (score 0):

I think an combination of `SimpleXMLElement::count` with `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` could help you to identify a single entry and add another fake entry. I think this is a bad practice, but if you have no access to the mobile appliction, this could be a workaround, if the empty entry will cause no sideeffects.

But to achieve a clean solution i suggest modifying the code in the mobile application.

```
$xml = SimpleXMLElement();

// get your data into $xml here

$creneaus = $xml->xpath('/infogeneral/day/creneau');

foreach ($creneaus as $creneau) {
    if ( $creneau->count() == 1 ) {
        $parent = $creneau->xpath( '..' );
        $creneauEmpty = simplexml_load_string('<creneau><heure>...</creneau>');
        $parent->addChild($creneauEmpty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take a look at that. But I think I can not add a fake child if I want things to work fine.. In fact, in my app (iOS), I have an if statement to  handle whether it's an array or a dictionary, and it's working fine. But the Android dev wants me to handle that in the xml to json api.

Comment: I read about typecasting into an object here: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/php_pitfalls/ (Search for "(object)")
i will investigate that later, if i can find some time